# SVN Merging Via Eclipse Differs Compared to Command Line

Tags: eclipse, svn

I had some issues integrating my changes to the main repository (moving my branch into the trunk) recently and have some issues understanding why I was experiencing these issues.

Here is the exact error I was getting:

```
Working copy and merge source not ready for reintegration
svn: Cannot merge into a working copy that has local modifications
```

For what I understand, this means I have to update my branch to head and rebase with trunk before moving my branch into the trunk.

Here are the steps I performed in Eclipse:

```
<branch> > Team > Update to HEAD
<branch> > Team > Merge (Targeting <trunk>)
<branch> > Team > Commit...
```

This produced the error mentioned above.

Performing the following steps via Command Line did not cause any issues:

```
svn co <svn path to branch>
cd <specifically modified module of branch>
svn merge <path to branch module in trunk>
svn commit -m "<Commit message>"
```

Could someone help me understand why Eclipse produced these issues. I understand the steps are slightly different, but I still do not see why I should have ran into those issues.

Additionally let me know if any of my terminology is wrong and needs any correcting or further explanation. Any and all constructive criticism appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn: Cannot merge into a working copy that has local modifications`
means that you have local modifications not committed (you have a *dirt* workspace).

If you are sure that you do not have local modifications, then you can try to clean pristine:
`Team >  Cleanup`

Or/and just delete project (delete contents on disk marked) and import from SVN again.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the alternate solution as well.